# Get apache server status Java/C

Tags: java, c, apache, xampp

I want write my own XAMPP Gui to run custom commands instead using CLI.

I already read how to launch bash command using Java or C

C:

```
system("command to start apache server");
```

Java:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls");
pb.start();
```

but I don't know how detect the server's status (running or not).

My first idea was to send an http request to the server and read the responce. There is a best way?

Comment: I mean 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("command to start apache server");

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick lies in your question. You could use the command to get the process running or not using a

ps -ef | grep java

command from your embedded java program.